# Multiple identical collection_select tags in a form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have multiple identical collection selects inside a single form.  I prefer this over a multiple select list for aesthetic and UX reasons.  I have to use a terrible kludge to make everything work right, and I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this:

From the view:

```
  <% 3.times do |i| %> 
    <%= collection_select("selected_item_" + i.to_s.to_s, :name, @items, :name, :name, { :include_blank => true }, { id: "selected_item_" + i.to_s }) %>  
  <% end %>
```

From the controller:

```
ItemContainer = Struct.new(:name)

3.times do |i|
  param = ('selected_item_' + i.to_s).to_sym
  instance_variable = '@' + param_name
  if params[param] && !params[param].empty?
    @selected_items << params[param][:name]
    instance_variable_set(instance_variable, ItemContainer.new(params[param][:name]))
  end
end

@selected_channels.each....  # do what I need to with these selections
```

Most of these gymnastics are needed to ensure that the item is still selected if the page is refreshed.  If there were some way to force collection select to use arrays, that would be the answer, but I couldn't make that work.

Comment: What is the problem exactly. Is saving working ok?

Comment: Yeah, everything works fine; it's just that using `instance_variable_set` (to use the Ruby docs phrasing) frustrates "the efforts of the class’s author to attempt to provide proper encapsulation."  IOW, this is an ugly hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understang right you're looking for `selegt_tag` method (docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag)

You can write something like this

```
select_tag "people[]", options_from_collection_for_select(@people, "id", "name")
select_tag "people[]", options_from_collection_for_select(@people, "id", "name")
```

and it youd output two selects for people, which would be sent as an array on submit.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the `[]` naming in your `collection_select` calls then the params will send over the data as an array

I am a bit confused as to the usage of collection_select here as it doesn't seem like you are using a model object? this example using select_tag - might be able to come up with something more appropriate to your issue if the model structures were known

```
# run this in the loop
# set selected_value to appropriate value if needed to pre-populate the form
<%= select_tag('name[]', 
    options_from_collection_for_select(@items, 'name', 'name', selected_value),
    { include_blank: true }   
  )
%>
```

in controller update/create action

```
# this works because the select tag 'name' is named with [] suffix
# but you have to ensure it is set to empty array if none are passed, usually only issue with checkboxes
names = params[:name] || [] 
names.each do |name|
  puts name
end
```

side note: you can use string interpolation with ruby double quotes in places of `+` for string concatenation

```
<%= collection_select("selected_item_#{i}",
    :name, 
    @items, 
    :name,  
    :name, 
    { include_blank: true }, 
    { id: "selected_item_#{i}" }
  ) 
%>
```

see also: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select

Comment: Thanks.  Both answers were similar and correct, so I went with the one I saw first.